# How to convert the column to row data using bash script and create the csv file

Tags: bash, shell, awk

Have some data in text file (input data) that I want to convert in the CSV file. How can I create in below format in bash script?

- Input data

  - a=1
  - b=2
  - c=3
  - d=4
- Output data (CSV file data)

  - a,b,c,d
  - 1,2,3,4

---

Without Array

```
i=0
 while IFS='=' read -r key value
 do
    echo "$key"
    echo "$value"
    echo "$i"
    i=$((i+1))
 done < "stats.txt"
```

With Array:

```
 i=0
 j=0
 while IFS='=' read -r key value
 do 
 echo arrayKey[`$i`]="$key"
 echo arrayVal[`$j`]="$value"
 i=`$((i+1))`
 j=`$((j+1))`
 done < status.txt
```

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: If it's supposed to be a bash script, what is the perl tag doing in the question?

Comment: All the questions that you've asked on this site have been downvoted. I would suggest taking a [tour] and learning [ask] better questions.

Comment: Anubhava, I have  some code like below one i=0
j=0
while IFS='=' read -r key value
do
    echo arrayKey[0][$i]="$key"
 echo arrayVal[1][$j]="$value"
 i=$((i+1))
 j=$((j+1))
done <stat.txt

Comment: Edit that to your question and we'll revote.

Comment: Adding code made this a normal question, I voted to reopen.   One more thing: please add a statement on what is wrong with the code you show.  (Typically you'd show output.) Also, since you accepted an awk answer I added the awk tag. Please remember for the future -- show what you have and state/show what the problem with it is. It makes it a legitimate question, and you'll get so much more in answers when people can see your work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In awk:

```
$ awk '                                  # awk it is
BEGIN { FS="=";OFS=",";start=1 }         # separators
NR>=start && $0!="" {                    # define start line and remove empties
    # sub(/\r/,"",$NF)                   # uncomment to remove windows line endings
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)                   # all cols 
        a[i]=a[i] (NR==start?"":OFS) $i  # gather
    }
END {                                    # in the end
    for(j=1;j<i;j++)                     # all ..
        print a[j]                       # outputed
}' file
a,b,c,d
1,2,3,4
```

Comment: How to delete or skip the first column from file

Comment: Change the value of var `start`.

Comment: When i tried to execute the same code on production. Data not getting transform.  Could you please suggest.

Comment: That's really hard to say based on that error description only. Please be more specific. If the data is different in the production, post it. Describe the environment and awk versions etc.

Comment: Same script, Same data, same file name but two diff env, On production it 3.1.7 and local 4.1.4. Is there any major diff b/w 2 version. I cant update the server as it use my many application.

Comment: I'm unaware of the differencies. I noticed that it fails if the file is in Windows format (`\r\n` line endings). You could add `sub(/\r/,"",$NF)` to the code, I'll put it in comments to right place.

Comment: I've found that if the file ends with two or more return carriages, then the output is empty.  Is that the issue you are seeing, Dinesh?

Comment: Seems that way. I added empty line removal to the code: `&& $0!=""` .

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -lnE'push @d, [split /\s*=\s*/] }{ 
    for $i (0..$#d) { say join ",", map $_->[$i], @d }
' input.txt
```

---

Lines are processed into the array `@d` of arrayrefs which contain fields `([a,1], [b,2] ...)`. After that, in the end block started by `}{`, the elements at the same index from each arrayref are extracted with `map` and joined with `,`, for all (both) indices.

This is like building and transposing a matrix.

If more data were given, like `a = 1,10,100` (or `a = 1 10 100`), then  `split /\s*[=,]\s*/` (or with `/\s*[=\s]\s*/` pattern) can be used, with the rest of the code unchanged.

I couldn't find a way to extract all same-index slices ("columns") without an explicit loop.

Comment: how is this supportive of bad behavior?  (which I presume is the -1)  why don't you just vote-to-close early, what _I always do_, and we wouldn't have a problem

Comment: Compensating. ++

Comment: @JamesBrown  Thank you for support.  I didn't take this question seriously (it just asks for code, which is why the answer isn't friendly). I just didn't understand that vote.  My only gripe with what I posted is that I didn't manage to take all slices w/o a loop.